# Can we create a View with model in sitecore without creating a Controller?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

Is it possible to create a View with a model but without creating any controller in Sitecore MVC 7.2.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you maybe mean a view rendering? A Sitecore view rendering only uses a view and a model, and the Controller is handled by Sitecore. I think this is a good tutorial for adding view renderings with models: http://www.sitecore.net/de-de/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2012/06/sitecore-mvc-playground-part-5-using-models.aspx

Comment: This is what worked for me. I have documented the same here - [Can we create a View with model in sitecore without creating a Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623985/can-we-create-a-view-with-model-in-sitecore-without-creating-a-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.
It's easiest with [Glass Mapper](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc.aspx), but you can do it out of the box as well.

Glass implements a processor in the `mvc.getModel` pipeline that looks for the model type in the View Rendering definition and creates an instance for you before executing the view.
See [this tutorial](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial12.aspx) for an example.

Out of the box you can create a Model item underneath `/sitecore/Layout/Models` that refers to a class.
You can then select the model item in model field of your View Rendering.

Comment: Is it possible without any external add in like Glass Mapper?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean with out of the box

Comment: I am totally new to Sitecore. Is there any simple tutorial you are aware of? if so can you provide those links/steps? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this the "plain" Sitecore way. Just right-click the item "Sitecore/layout/renderings" and insert an item of type "View Rendering". Add the path of your view in the "path"-field.

This video is a very good introduction to Sitecore MVC http://youtu.be/i3Mwcphtz4w

This is also a very good source for learning about Sitecore MVC: http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/